# sp_helptext and definition of view being NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

When I try to `EXEC sp_helptext 'dbo.VW_myname'` I get the following:

> There is no text for object 'dbo.VW_myname'.

And I get a `NULL` when i look at the definition of the view:

```
select definition
from sys.objects     o
join sys.sql_modules m on m.object_id = o.object_id
where o.object_id = object_id( 'dbo.VW_myname')
  and o.type      = 'V'
```

My question is two-fold: How come, I can't see the text behind the creation of that view and how can I find out how it is executed?

Comment: `how can I find out how it is executed?` A view is queried the same as a table. If you do, `Select * From dbo.vw_myname` What do you get?

Comment: Also, you may not have the proper permissions.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I get the results of the query.

Comment: What is your access level on the SQL Server?

Comment: @WEI_DBA not sure. definitely not an adminstrator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [happens](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1593/granting-view-definition-permission-to-a-user-or-role-in-sql-server/) when you don't have the `VIEW DEFINITION` permission.

Ask your DBA to [grant you this permission](https://serverfault.com/a/586449/58957).